# WH40K 10ed: Is “change to a 6” and “change to a unmodified 6” means the same? Why? Or why not?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The question is about Warhammer 40,000 10th edition rules.

Take a look on Infernal Master and Fluxmaster

**Infernal Master** (Thousand Sons, index page 35)

> Glimpse of Eternity (Psychic)
> Once per turn, you can change the result of one Hit roll, one Wound roll, one Damage roll or one saving throw made for this model **to an unmodified 6**.

**Fluxmaster** (Legiones Daemonica, index page 40)

> Altered Reality (Psychic)
> Once per battle round, after a Hit roll, a Wound roll or a saving throw is made for this model, you can change the result of that roll **to a 6**.

Are these abilities do the same? If yes, why does they have different spelling? If no, what’s the difference in practice?